# Instanciate an injector with multiple AbstractGinModule

Tags: gwt, guice, gwt-gin

In google Guice, I can create an injector based on multiple module with the function `createInjector`.

Because I use `GWT.create` to instanciate the injector in GoogleGin, is it possible to create a Ginjector based on multiple `AbstractGinModule`.

If we can't, how do you organize your code to avoid having all your binding in the same Module ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the following code to create injector which is using multiple modules:

```
@GinModules({ ClientDispatchModule.class, MyClientModule.class })
public interface MyAppGinjector extends Ginjector {

    AppPresenter getAppPresenter();

    PlaceManager getPlaceManager();

    EventBus getEventBus();
}
```